# Applying a custom header for ContextMenu

Tags: java, android, android-layout, contextmenu

I'm trying to apply a custom header to the `ContextMenu` of a `ListView`. Here's the code.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    View header = View.inflate(getSherlockActivity(),
            R.id.context_menu_header, (ViewGroup) v);
    TextView title = (TextView) header
            .findViewById(R.id.context_menu_title);
    title.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    menu.setHeaderView(header);

    android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

This code fails with a `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050038 type #0x12 is not valid`. In the line `View header = View.inflate(getSherlockActivity(), R.id.context_menu_header, (ViewGroup) v);`. I'm guessing probably because of param `(ViewGroup) v`. How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `R.id.context_menu_header` instead of a `R.layout.layout_file` and I had to pass null for the last parameter of the View.inflate method.

Comment: The real problem in your code was that you used `R.id.context_menu_header` instead of a `R.layout.layout_file` and also you should pass `null` for the last parameter of the `View.inflate` method.

Answer (score 0):

My first though is an error in one of your XML-files. Some ID that is not defined correctly or something. It would be helpful if you would post some more code including the XML-file :)

Comment: Solved it. :)  see my answer.