# Unable to apply custom header to context menu(android)

Tags: android, layout, header, android-contextmenu

HI I am developing small android application. In my application I am showing one context menu.
every thing is working fine only problem is that I am not able to set header view to my context menu.
My code looks like

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    LayoutInflater headerInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSherlockActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) headerInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.context_menu_header, null);

    menu.setHeaderView(header);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Edit Profile Pic");

    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_camera, menu);
}
```

and my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/context_menu_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/actionbar" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

It's not taking that layout file as header view... I also read this [Applying a custom header for ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205812/applying-a-custom-header-for-contextmenu)

But that's not working for me.. 
Need help thank you....

Comment: are you getting any exception? if so post the logcat

Comment: No; I am able to run my code without any exception.. It shows me default view of context menu but not applying that layout to my heder part ... That is `menu.setHeaderView(header);` is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I set header title after set header view it's not applying that view. Insted of that set header title in xml view itself and set title when u r applying header view. like in following manner..

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
LayoutInflater headerInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSherlockActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) headerInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.context_menu_header, null);

   // menu.setHeaderView(header);
  TextView title = (TextView) header
                .findViewById(R.id.header_textView);
        title.setText("Edit Profile Pic");
    menu.setHeaderView(header);
//menu.setHeaderTitle("Edit Profile Pic");

MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_camera, menu);
}
```

and it will work fine. Its same as this question [Applying a custom header for ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205812/applying-a-custom-header-for-contextmenu).

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

In Android 8.1, the ContextMenu will create a StandardMenuPopup, and it will never call menu.getHeaderView for your custom header view. That means setHeaderView() is unused.

```
private boolean tryShow() {
    ...
    if (mShowTitle && mMenu.getHeaderTitle() != null) {
            FrameLayout titleItemView =
                    (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                            com.android.internal.R.layout.popup_menu_header_item_layout,
                            listView,
                            false);
            TextView titleView = (TextView) titleItemView.findViewById(
                    com.android.internal.R.id.title);
            if (titleView != null) {
                titleView.setText(mMenu.getHeaderTitle());
            }
            titleItemView.setEnabled(false);
            listView.addHeaderView(titleItemView, null, false);

            // Update to show the title.
            mPopup.show();
        }
    ...
}
```